# How to find the value for aadSessionkey when deploying a Kubernetes template in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rm-template, azure-aks

I am trying to use a template to deploy a managed Kubernetes cluster (AKS). My problem is that the template has a parameter `aadSessionKey` that I seem to be unable to locate.

I assume the expanded name of the parameter is Azure AD SessionKey. When I look in the portal, I can see that my Azure AD has a *Name*, *Application ID* and *Object ID*, but nothing that looks like a session key, nor a way to generate such a thing.

I am using a free trial account if that matters.

Comment: Can you show this template?

Comment: How do you get that template and what's the detail content? Based on these article: [Create an AKS cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-rm-template#create-an-aks-cluster); [Deploy a managed Kubernetes Cluster (AKS).](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-aks-advanced-networking/), there isn't such parameters.  Or do you mean there is input box in Kubernetes deploy task in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Does Azure DevOps means [Azure DevOps pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops)? Which task you used?

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try entering any random value and try deploying it. It seems like this is system generated value which is not to be filled by clients. This has been present in template for some other reason.

Ref - https://twitter.com/ashtonkj/status/1196384865672925184

Comment: If this works, please vote up and accept the answer so that people can search for the solution without wasting time.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem, but I suspect it is the trial account that is the problem now. Will re-try in a few days with a paid account.